# Differential-gradient equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, gradient-flows

Are there general methods for solving differential equations involving gradient, for example:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$

Or their systems:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dF(x,y)}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dF(x,y)}{dy}$

where $F(x)$ or $F(x,y)$ - arbitrary function, for example $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ or $sech(x)^2 \cdot sech(y)^2$